# Loopj timeout exception in Android

Tags: android, exception, timeout, connection-timeout, loopj

I am having a strange problem with Loopj Async HTTP library. I sometimes get the response using GET or POST, sometimes the response comes after a long time, some times the response does not come at all. This happens only when wifi is used. I have used loopj in so many projects and those work fine with wifi but not this project. When I use my mobile data 3G connection, always the response comes. I have overridden the onFaliure method and this is what I get when the response from server does not come:

```
E/statusCode(31980): 0
E/headers(31980): null
E/Throwable(31980): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
E/errorResponse(31980): null
```

An Exception also gets printed on logcat:

```
04-16 10:58:18.795: W/System.err(31980): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
04-16 10:58:18.795: W/System.err(31980):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
04-16 10:58:18.795: W/System.err(31980):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-16 10:58:18.795: W/System.err(31980):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-16 10:58:18.795: W/System.err(31980):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-16 10:58:18.795: W/System.err(31980):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-16 10:58:18.795: W/System.err(31980):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:74)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:91)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-16 10:58:18.800: W/System.err(31980):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-16 10:58:18.800: V/JsonHttpResponseHandler(31980): response body is null, calling onFailure(Throwable, JSONObject)
```

I would greatly appreciate if some solution can be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.setTimeout(60000);
```

That will set the request timeout and then you will have the time you need.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was introduced on 1.4.4;

Try use this library instead: https://github.com/leonardoxh/AsyncOkHttpClient

This library uses OkHttp (from Square Inc.) instead of Apache Http Client, and also is the codes for 2.0 Loopj Library

;)

Answer (score 1):

More than an year later this error keeps popping up from time to time. Quite interestingly even though the stacktrace says

> "response body is null, calling onFailure(Throwable, JSONObject)"

The actual method that's invoked is `onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, (JSONObject) null);`

This is as per line 231 [JsonHttpResponseHandler.java](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.java) this would suggest that the method with the following signature is the one to be overridden:

```
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse)
```